# Rails - No database found after creating DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I switched to a new Macbook and when i tried to work on my project locally.

When i run `rails s` it keeps telling me the local DB doesn't exist.

When i try to run:

```
rake db:create
```

It tells me that the there is no user with the name `myusername`

I ran `psql -U postgres`

and then i ran `\du`

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 name      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 dev       | Create DB                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 name2     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

and i can see my user there with access to the database.

Comment: Made this questions because i couldn't find any solutions online; Incase anybody runs into this issue after cloning their drive to a new Macbook with a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running

`psql -U postgres`

`postgres=# \du`

to see the list of users.

Once i found the user i went to `config/database.yml`

and i set the username under development

```
 development:
  <<: *default
  database: swiftypost_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  username: my_username
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so that others know you don't still need help.

Comment: @coreyward have to wait till tomorrow, will do though.